# Text gets cut off when pinching/scaling/resizing UITtextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I have a UITextView that can be scaled, rotated and resized using gestures inside a UIImageView.
When I scale or resize it and then type in some text, the text container changes size and the text gets cut off.
I tried changing the size of the text to resize it to fit the container. I also tried changing the container frame inside the textView but it didn't work.
Can anyone help me please?

Here are some images to help out to see what is happening visually.

Normal Image:

https://ibb.co/eAz3Lv

Irregular Image:

https://ibb.co/g932DF

Thank you for your help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution!
I put my UITextView inside a UIView and it works properly right now.